# How to OCR a pdf with google cloud vision?

Tags: c#, pdf, google-cloud-vision

I am using C#.net on my laptop Windows 10

I have the code for OCRing an image (png , jpg) works fine

I need to get the pdf files to work

but a friend told me that pdf can be sent directly to google APIs and get OCRed without the need of converting pdf to image then send an image.

is this possible? if so, how?

```
    private string GetTextFromImage(Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image filePath)
    {
        var response = Client.DetectText(filePath);
        var resultList = new List<ResultElement>();

        foreach (var annotation in response)
        {
            resultList.Add(new ResultElement
            {
                Description = annotation.Description,
                Location = annotation.BoundingPoly.ToString()
            });
        }

        return resultList.First().Description;
    }

    private Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image GetImageFromPath(string filePath)
    {
        return Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(filePath);
    }
```

## Edit

Thanks Ricco

but the code returned this script not a the pdf text

```
{ "responses": [ { "responses": [ { "fullTextAnnotation": { "pages": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en", "confidence": 0.92 }, { "languageCode": "fil", "confidence": 0.02 }, { "languageCode": "af", "confidence": 0.01 } ] }, "width": 841, "height": 595, "blocks": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en", "confidence": 0.33 }, { "languageCode": "fil", "confidence": 0.29 } ] }, "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.587395966, "y": 0.9210084 }, { "x": 0.369797856, "y": 0.640336156 }, { "x": 0.4530321, "y": 0.5126051 }, { "x": 0.6706302, "y": 0.7932773 } ] }, "paragraphs": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "fil", "confidence": 0.47 }, { "languageCode": "en", "confidence": 0.39 } ] }, "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.587395966, "y": 0.9210084 }, { "x": 0.372176, "y": 0.6386555 }, { "x": 0.416171223, "y": 0.5714286 }, { "x": 0.6313912, "y": 0.8554622 } ] }, "words": [ { "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.529132, "y": 0.8436975 }, { "x": 0.4649227, "y": 0.761344552 }, { "x": 0.4803805, "y": 0.73613447 }, { "x": 0.544589758, "y": 0.8201681 } ] }, "symbols": [ { "text": "M", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "text": "e", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "text": "n", "confidence": 1 }, { "text": "g", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "text": "m", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "text": "e", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "text": "n", "confidence": 1 }, { "property": { "detectedBreak": { "type": "SPACE" } }, "text": "g", "confidence": 0.99 } ], "confidence": 0.99 }, { "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.460166454, "y": 0.754621863 }, { "x": 0.445897728, "y": 0.73613447 }, { "x": 0.461355537, "y": 0.712605059 }, { "x": 0.475624263, "y": 0.731092453 } ] }, "symbols": [ { "text": "L", "confidence": 0.99 }, { "property": { "detectedBreak": { "type": "EOL_SURE_SPACE" } }, "text": "u", "confidence": 0.99 } ], "confidence": 0.99 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.58501786, "y": 0.877310932 }, { "x": 0.5731272, "y": 0.8605042 }, { "x": 0.5862069, "y": 0.840336144 }, { "x": 0.5980975, "y": 0.857142866 } ] }, "symbols": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "a", "confidence": 0.62 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "t", "confidence": 0.98 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ], "detectedBreak": { "type": "SPACE" } }, "text": "e", "confidence": 0.94 } ], "confidence": 0.84 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.568371, "y": 0.8537815 }, { "x": 0.549346, "y": 0.8302521 }, { "x": 0.5636147, "y": 0.8084034 }, { "x": 0.581450641, "y": 0.833613455 } ] }, "symbols": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "K", "confidence": 0.92 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "e", "confidence": 0.98 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ], "detectedBreak": { "type": "SPACE" } }, "text": "y", "confidence": 0.98 } ], "confidence": 0.96 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "boundingBox": { "normalizedVertices": [ { "x": 0.5457788, "y": 0.8235294 }, { "x": 0.5279429, "y": 0.8016807 }, { "x": 0.542211652, "y": 0.779831946 }, { "x": 0.560047567, "y": 0.803361356 } ] }, "symbols": [ { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "L", "confidence": 0.96 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ] }, "text": "a", "confidence": 1 }, { "property": { "detectedLanguages": [ { "languageCode": "en" } ], "detectedBreak": { "type": "SPACE" } }, "text": "b", "co
```

How to get the pdf text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a code snippet to OCR a PDF file that is stored in google cloud storage. This is using [batch annotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch) that has a limit of processing a **maximum of 5 pages per request**.

EDIT: Code now uses a local file. This will return the response containing the content of the PDF file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using Google.Protobuf;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class QuickStart
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("your/complete/local/file/path/here.pdf");
            var content_byte = ByteString.CopyFrom(bytes);
    
            var syncRequest = new AnnotateFileRequest
            {
                InputConfig = new InputConfig
                {
                    Content = content_byte,
                    // Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
                    MimeType = "application/pdf"
    
                }
            };
    
            syncRequest.Features.Add(new Feature
            {
                Type = Feature.Types.Type.DocumentTextDetection
            });
    
            List<AnnotateFileRequest> requests =
                new List<AnnotateFileRequest>();
            requests.Add(syncRequest);
    
            var response = client.BatchAnnotateFiles(requests);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but does it work with a file on my computer?  how to use this code in my code above?

Comment: @asmgx I edited the code to use a local pdf file from your computer. Your code above uses `DetectText()` which is intended for image inputs, thus the code provided for PDF cannot be used for your code above.

Comment: Please read my edited comment in the question

Comment: @asmgx unfortunately Vision API does not return a literal converted PDF to text file. At the end of the response there is a key `text:` that contains the whole text of the PDF. You might need to parse this response for you to use it.